# Making a plane fit to fly after accidental emergency exit / slide deployment

Tags: emergency-slide

Every so often there is a report of a person openening an ( armed ) emergency exit unauthorised on the ground leading to a slide deployment.

Often this is followed by the flight leaving after deplaning / arresting the person involved but with ( say) an hour's delay.

What i was wondering is how they manage this? Isn't the emergency slide packed in a very specific manner by trained packers? Or do airports carry spare pre-packed slides that they can replace into the doors?

Or are aircraft allowed to fly with a non-operantional single slide as a MEL item?

Just was curious to know since one hour sounded like a pretty quick fix.

Comment: Can you link an article where they actually left with only an hour delay? I couldn't find one in a quick search...

Comment: I'm no expert by any means, but it might be possible that, if the plane is at a maintenance hub, they may be able to replace the entire door, including a pre-packed slide, in only an hour. Of course, that's just me thinking out loud, and I have no experience or evidence to back this up, hence a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Interesting, @Bianfable. Last flight I took (A320 or 321, I believe), there was a large bulge in the main entry door that appeared to have the slide in it. Maybe it depends on which slide is deployed. Maybe I completely misinterpreted what I was looking at.

Comment: "The flight" may depart an hour later, but it may be a different aircraft  used for that flight. Replacing the door (big, heavy, multiple hinges needing exact alignment) would be far more involved than replacing the packed slide. Replacing a door in an hour would be like an Indy pit crew replacing 4 tires in 20 seconds... possible, but not going to happen in real life with line mechanics (or your local tire shop).

Comment: @FreeMan Actually, looking at escape slide deployment videos ([737](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFGuDV6Rle0), [A320](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLwJ0KV_0aY)), it looks like you're right. They are stored in that bulge in the door. I remember seeing some image with a hatch below a door saying CAUTION ESCAPE SLIDE, but I don't remember which aircraft that was...

Comment: If you're going there, @RalphJ, it would be like an F1 crew replacing 4 tires in 2.3 seconds. ;)  Fair points, all, thanks for the insight. Many things I hadn't considered, but as noted originally, it was speculation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be an MEL item on some aircraft (see) [Operation of Wide Body Jets with Door/Slide Inoperative](https://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/policy%20letters/pl-001_r03_d00.htm).  I'm not aware of single aisle aircraft (e.g. B737, etc.), except for cargo-only configurations, providing MEL relief for inoperative door slides.

If it's not an item that can be deferred per the MEL for a particular aircraft it's likely going to take at least  an hour (probably much more depending on the circumstances, type of airplane, etc.) to repack/replace the slide, do the paperwork, reboard the passengers, etc., even if the aircraft is at a company maintenance base airport with the necessary maintenance personnel and equipment.  If the aircraft is at a non-maintenance base it would be hard to image resolving the issue in an hour.

Can you provide a source for the report you are referring to?

Comment: Replacing would be a ***lot*** faster than repacking the deployed slide.  A missing slide couldn't be MEL'd, but a maintenance ferry might be allowed to reposition the aircraft with only pilots aboard.

Comment: @RalphJ I  generally agree. Ferry flight would probably work (no pax). B737, probably others allow cargo only versions mel relief without all slides (with provisos). Some wide-body jets allow per mel an inop Door/Slide. Replacing,  if available,  would be faster. But by the time all work, reboarding etc. was done pushing back in an hour would be optimistic.  I've only seen it once and it was a mess and took quite awhile to resolve (at a maintenance base.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [testing/inspection interval of slides](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52921/can-the-emergency-slide-be-re-used-after-it-has-been-deployed), [discussion about time to repack](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=388545), [two hour delay for a pack that detached](https://www.latimes.com/travel/la-tr-fly-guy-20171126-story.html), [article mentions a four hour and an eight hour delay](https://simpleflying.com/this-product-should-help-reduce-accidental-emergency-slide-deployment/).